# Magento 1.6.2 Multiple Stores

Tags: magento

I am trying to integrate multiple magento sites within the one installation. From what I have found i need to use a parked domain method however I have tried various methods to get it all working however I keep getting the 2nd store redirecting to the main store so I am looking for the best method to allow me to run multiple websites.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 8):

We currently have 4 stores all sharing one Magento installation & set of products. Each has it's own unique URL.

**Create your Stores**

1. Go to System -> Manage Stores
2. Click on `Create Website`. In the `Name` field, enter your store name. In the `Code` field, enter a unique code [lowercase & without spaces - we're going to give it a code of **domain1** for our example] (to be used later) & Save.
3. Click on `Create Store`. In the `Website` field, select the website from step 2. In the `Name` field, enter a name. In the `Root Category` field, select the Root Category for your store & Save.
4. Click on `Create Store View`. Select the store you just created (from the dropdown menu) for Store. Type a name for your store in the Name field (Example from Magento is English Store). In the Code field, enter a unique string to identify the store view (just like for your store). Change the Status to Enabled & Save.
5. Repeat for all your stores

**Configure your stores in the Magento Admin Configuration Section**

1. Go to System -> Configuration
2. In the Store Scope (top-left dropdown), choose your first **Store**.
3. Choose **Web** from the Left-side menu
4. Open the `Unsecure` & `Secure` sections
5. Change the domains to what they would be (i.e. - http://www.domain1.com/) *Don't forget the trailing slash at the end*
6. Repeat for all stores

**Server Config (for Magento versions 1.4.0.1 and greater)**

1. Point your domain (e.g. - www.domain1.com) to your server where your single Magento instance is installed
2. Set up a Pointer/Parked domain on your server (see your Host's instructions or contact them)
3. In the `.htaccess` file on the root of your install, put in the following code for each of your stores

> SetEnvIf Host .*domain1.com
>   MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain1 **<- This was your important code from step 2 under Create your Stores**
>  SetEnvIf Host
>   .*domain1.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website

This set of 2 must be repeated for every domain you have.

**For our particular stores/domains (might find useful)**

Some servers, particularly those running Litespeed Web Server, the `SetEnvIf` directive does not get recognized in the `.htaccess` file. This was particularly true for us.

We had to do the following

Find **RewriteBase /** or **RewriteBase /magento/** or `etc`

> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*domain1.com [NC] 
>
>   RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:domain1] 
>   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*domain1.com [NC] 
>
>   RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:website]

We also have symlinks set up on our server (under each or our domains) to point to our main domain's folders (for the `app`, `includes`, `js`, `lib`, `media`, `shell`, `skin`, `var`)

Answer (score 2):

### Multi Store in Magento v1.6.2

- in the VirtualHost configuration set the DocumentRoot to where you have your Magento installed (something like /var/www/magento), so it will be the same for every domain as we want only one Magento install for each domain
- in Magento's admin, go to *System -> Manage Stores* and create your websites with their stores and store views (before that you'll have created one root category for each website). Reindex after everything is created
- go to *System -> Configuration* and change the scope (the dropdown on the upper left) to one of the website. Go to the *(General) Web -> Unsecure* tab, uncheck the "*Use Default*" and indicate the domain in the **Base URL** field. Do the same for the secure
- open the *.htaccess* at the root of your Magento install and at the end of it add the rules to determine which website to show according to the domain. For example, if you have set the codes *website1* for domain1.com and *website2* for domain2.com, put this:

  SetEnvIf Host ^domain1.com$ MAGE_RUN_CODE=website1
  SetEnvIf Host ^domain2.com$ MAGE_RUN_CODE=website2
  SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE website

and you're all set :)
HTH

Answer (score 0):

Did you change your base urls for the second store configuration?

Navigate to:

System>Configuration>Web>Unsecure
System>Configuration>Web>Secure

Then change the Current Configuration Scope (top of left sidebar): your second store config

Deselect use default and enter your second store's path:

Base URL : http://yourdomain.com/
Secure Base URL: https://yourdomain.com/

Comment: Hi , yes both have been selected and changed to the correct domain, but no luck as yet